# Business logic validations in Django: Model or ModelForm?

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have the following model:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Event(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
    location = models.ManyToManyField(Location)
```

The `Event` model has two invariants:

- `end` can't be before `start`
- a `Location` can't have overlapping events

What would be a better pattern in Django: validating this in your form (`EventForm.clean_end()`) or in your model (`Event.clean()`)? According to the docs, when you define a `clean()` method in your model, it won't be automatically called when using `save()`, so when manipulating objects outside the Form API I can't really see the added value (unless you call `full_clean()` by yourself). Also, in my case, my application only has one `EventModelForm` which manipulates `Event` objects, so both options would be equally DRY.

In short: should I put these kind of validations in my models or in my forms?

Comment: "According to the docs, when you define a clean() method in your model, it won't be automatically called when using save()" => Indeed, but you just need to override your model's `save()` method to add the call to `self.full_clean()`.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned I favor "smart" models so I tend to add "strong" invariants enforcement at the model level (forcing validation in the model's  `save()` method) unless I have a good reason to do otherwise - but _as long as there's one single place where events are created/edited_ this won't make much of a difference. Until someone else takes on your code and adds another way to create/edit events without bothering to read the form's validation and move it to the model... (been here, done that :-/)